# kubectl auth can-i says I can, but I can’t

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I am baffled. kubectl says I can (via the `kubectl auth can-i` subcommand), but then when I go to perform the action, I can't.

I have installed `kubectl` on a docker image which is running on a pod managed by a `Deployment`. When I `kubectl exec -it` into that pod (which only has a single container) I get this.

```
user@my-pod:~$ kubectl auth can-i get secrets -n myNamespace
yes

user@my-pod:~$ kubectl get secrets -n myNamespace
Error from server (Forbidden):
secrets is forbidden:
User "system:serviceaccount:myNamespace:myServiceAccount"
cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "myNamespace"
```

Here is how my serviceaccount is configured

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: myServiceAccount
  namespace: myNamespace

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: myRole
  namespace: myNamespace
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "describe"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: myRoleBinding
  namespace: myNamespace
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: myRole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myServiceAccount
  namespace: myNamespace
```

I am first of all curious to know if I am using [`kubectl auth can-i`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#checking-api-access) incorrectly.

Secondly, I would like to be able to authorize this serviceaccount to make this API call. Is there a misconfiguration in my yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on here is the unfortunate collision between `kubectl` using `get` in *two different ways*, but `can-i` uses it only in **one** way. The list of supported verbs for `can-i` shows up on [its reference page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#auth)

Running:

`kubectl auth can-i get secrets -n myNamespace`

asks about the `get` verb specifically. That is the equivalent of `kubectl get secret my-awesome-secret`. If you want to know about `kubectl get secret`, that is using the **list** verb, and thus would be tested via:

`kubectl auth can-i list secrets -n myNamespace`

The distinction is called out in this table: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb

I believe the fix for your `Role` is to update `verbs:` to also include `"list"` if you want to enumerate the `Secret`s

```yaml
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "describe", "list"]
```